# Compile errors: boost

Tags: c++, boost

I installed boost on Ubuntu 14.04 with sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev.

If I want to compile a given program with this command

```
g++ -o prog givenProgram.cpp -I/usr/include/boost -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_serialization -lboost_random
```

, I get a lot of errors.

```
In file included from     ./include/pso.h:15:0,
             from givenProgram.cpp:1:
./include/particle.h:29:17: error: ‘boost’ is not a namespace-name
using namespace boost;
             ^
./include/particle.h:29:22: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
using namespace boost;
                  ^
./include/particle.h:58:11: error: ‘shared_ptr’ does not name a type
       shared_ptr<CostFunction> fit_func;        // pointer to a cost function
       ^
./include/particle.h:59:11: error: ‘shared_ptr’ does not name a type
       shared_ptr<RNG> rng;                      // pointer to a random number generator
       ^
./include/particle.h:118:62: error: ‘shared_ptr’ does not name a type
                     Particle ( int, CostFunction*, const shared_ptr<RNG> & );
                                                          ^
./include/particle.h:118:62: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]
./include/particle.h:118:72: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                     Particle ( int, CostFunction*, const shared_ptr<RNG> & );
                                                                    ^
./include/particle.h:119:47: error: ‘shared_ptr’ does not name a type
                     Particle ( int, const shared_ptr<CostFunction> &, const shared_ptr<RNG> & );
                                           ^
./include/particle.h:119:47: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]
./include/particle.h:119:57: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                     Particle ( int, const shared_ptr<CostFunction> &, const shared_ptr<RNG> & );
                                                     ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Introduction

The command-line options that you have passed to `g++` has nothing to do with the diagnostics issued, since you are specifying where to find the headers, and what objects it should link towards; you are not explicitly saying where it should find the definition of *boost::shared_ptr*.

The problem is that you are trying to use *namespace boost* without a proper definition of said namespace, and most likely you have not the relevant `#include`s within *givenProgram.cpp* so that the compiler knows about the names you are referencing.

---

#### Solution

Make sure that you have `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` in your source **before** you try to access something within *namespace boost*, and more specifically: **before** you try to use *boost::shared_ptr*.

The reason for this educated guess is that you haven't posted any errors regarding the compiler being unable to find the relevant `#include`, it complains because it cannot find the used names.